# Jquery Div Loading quickly

Tags: css

I was using javascript to load a div and my problem was it was instantaneously expanding. I'm trying to get the smooth expand where it appears to be moving frame by frame. I was turned on to Jquery in which I changed my information into Jquery The problem is that I'm back to square one of the content just appearing after I added the display:none; line into my style. If I remove the display:none then all my content shows on page-load rather then after it's clicked. If Anyone has a solution that would be appreciated. Thanks.
My Code is as follows

```
             <style>
  j { width:150px;
      display:none;
       }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Toggle</button>
  <br />

  <j>
My Content Goes here.

  </j>
<script>
    $("button").click(function () {
      $("j").slideToggle("slow");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: User defined. Sorry typed it up in a hurry but `code`<span class='j'>`code` I was using p, but it was interfering with the rest of my webpage distorting it.

Comment: Could it be because you are not loading your jQuery within the  $(document).ready(function()? http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

Comment: Highly Possible. Gonna check it out now.

Comment: You need to use a block level element like DIV instead of SPAN for this to work.

Comment: Trying to set up a div class for this the function no longer works. Adding the document ready function it was doing the same thing as before, so I think if anything, it's regressed.